# c++ constant variable defined by user

Tags: c++, math

My program uses number PI. It should be constant value `const double PI = 3.14`. I want that user of the program could define this constants during Initialization of the class. For example, one of them want 3.14 and another 3.1416926. And after definition it should be constant value, i.e. during program nobody can change it. How can I implement it?

Comment: "3.1416926" is a rather poor approximation of π.

Comment: Can you use `constexpr`?

Comment: Alternately if your compiler supports it you can use `M_PI` since pi is a constant with a well-defined value.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: Its better than 3.14

Comment: `355./113.` is my favourite :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a per-*instance* constant using a constant member:

```
class MyClass {
    MyClass(double pi): PI(pi) { ... }
    const double PI;
};
```

Each object creator my specify a value of `PI` to use, which is constant for the lifetime of that object:

```
MyClass obj1(3.14);
MyClass obj2(3.1416926);
```

Answer (score -1):

Put  `const double PI = 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944`  in a `.h` header file and include it in the `.cpp` file.
Or you will get that error.

**pi.h**

```
const double PI = 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944;
```

**Pi.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "pi.h"
using namespace std;

class  Pi_Class
{
        public:

        double m_PI;

        Pi_Class()
        {
                     cout<<PI<<" \n";
        }

        Pi_Class(double fPI )
        {
            m_PI=fPI; 
                    cout<<m_PI<<" \n";
        }
};


int main()
{

   Pi_Class Pi_one(3.141);
   Pi_Class Pi_two(3.1415926535);
   Pi_Class Pi_thr(3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944 );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't allow for multiple values of pi which is what the OP is after.